# Calculate interest on postgresql with trigger/function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, banking

I'm currently working on a simple banking application.

I have built a postgresql database, with the right tables and functions.

My problem is, that I am not sure how to calculate the interest rate on the accounts. I have a function that will tell me the balance, on a time.

If we say that we have a 1 month period, where I want to calculate the interest on the account. The balance looks like this:

```
  February     Balance
  1.           $1000
  3.           $300
  10.          $700
  27.          $500

  Balance on end of month: $500
```

My initial thoughts are to make a for loop, looping from the 1st in the month, to the last day in month, and adding the interest earned for that particular day in a row.

The function I want to use at end of month should be something like `addInterest(startDate,endDate,accountNumber)`, which should insert one row into the table, adding the earned rate.

Could someone bring me on the right track, or show me some good learning resources on PL/PGSQL?

**Edit**

I have been reading a bit on cursors. Should I use a cursor to walk through the table?

I find it a bit confusing to use cursors, anyone here with some well explained examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways of interest calculation in banking system.

Interest = Balance x Rate x Days / Year

**Types of Balances**

- Periodical Aggregate Balance
- Daily Aggregate Balance

**Types of Rates**

- Fixed Rate Dynamic Rate (according to balance)
- Dynamic Rate (according to term)
- Dynamic Rate (according to schedule)

**Types of Days/Schedules**

- End of Day Processing (One day)
- End of Month Processing (One month)
- End of Quarter Processing (Three months)
- End of Half Processing (Six months)
- End of Year Processing (One year)

**Year Formula**

- A year could consist of 365 or 366 days.
- Your user might want to override number of days in a year, maintain a separate year variable property in your application.

**Conclusion**

Interest should be calculated as a routine task. Best approach would be that would run on a schedule depending upon the frequency setup of individual accounts.

Comment: Excellent answer. I built a function with this formula, and it worked out pretty good. It turned out somewhat inefficient, because I had to calculate the balance for the account, for every day in the period, based on data from account start. (I know, that this is easily solvable with an balance on each transaction or something similar)
This was an school project, that I already have submitted. Thanks for the clarification, and the excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) has a section about loops and looping through query results. There are also examples of trigger functions written in pl/pgsql. The manual is very complete, it's the best source I know of.

Comment: I have looked into the manual before. It seems to be a fine resource on loops. But I was also thinking about the financial part. How are these calculations carried out in real systems?